# JS Switch Case is not matching the right value

Tags: javascript

I have a switch case, which tracks the key down press events and execute actions. For example, my switch matches the number 37 with 13 and executes the branch for case 13 when the left/ right arrow is pressed. I made sure the data type is parsed to int before, but I still see the issue. My switch-case logic is as below. Am I missing something here?

```
switch (evt.keyCode) {
                        case 27: // Escape
                            emit('editCanceled');
                            break;
                        case 9: // tab
                        case 37: // left
                        case 38: // up
                        case 39: // right
                        case 40: // down
                        case 13: // Enter
                            self.validateAndComplete();
                            break;
                        default:
                    }
```

Comment: You have multiple cases which all call `self.validateAndComplete`? Since both `13` and `37` are defined there, this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: What should happen if keyCode is 32?

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Is the switch statement not catching your keypresses? EDIT: I notice that there is no `break;` statement after `default:`.

Comment: That's how switch case works. You have to `break` if you don't want following things to apply. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: I realized this is the syntax issue. I removed cases 37 and 39, and my switch logic is working now. Thank for the input

Comment: Can someone add an answer to this question even though it works now? @TRao I think you should answer your own question so that other people with the same question as you can see the answer without going through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The following update to the switch logic ensures that my validateAndComplete is triggered for only enter and tab events. Left/ right/ up/ down key arrow events would not have any effect

```
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
                            case 27: // Escape
                                emit('editCanceled');
                                break;
                            case 9: // tab
                            case 13: // Enter
                                self.validateAndComplete();
                                break;
                            default:
                        }
```